# Can someone become Chabad?

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, chabad, baal-teshuva

How does a Jew who was not raised in Chabad become Chabadnik? Is it possible, and is there a process to do this?

Comment: I would recommend getting into contact with a Chabad-center in your area, by searching the nearest one [here](http://chabad.org/centers).

Comment: You can associate with them and follow their customs as closely as you want.  I doubt there is a line between "in" and "out".  I could be wrong.

Comment: Also worth contacting a non chabad rabbi. Rabbis of any one particular flavor will often rule anyone can become their flavor, when it's not always so simple

Comment: I would also CYLOR about it if it means changing your minhagim, especially if they are your family minhagim and/or if it means changing the pronunciation of davening.  I've heard that is quite problematic.

Answer (score 3):

"Can" as in "is it possible", or "is it allowed?" Possible? Sure! Plenty of people who were not raised Chabad or of Chabad-Lubavitch ancestry have switched over to Chabad. Just be aware that some "blue-blood" Lubavitchers may want their kids only marrying other "blue-bloods", and not those who recently joined the fold.

Allowed? If your ancestry is non-Hassidic, non-Hassidic rabbis tend to view Hassidic practices as ... inferior. But at the end of the day, find a community and flavor of Orthodox Judaism that works for you.

Comment: cf Geza https://jel.jewish-languages.org/words/1338